# How to open "extremely sturdy" door?

Tags: wasteland-2

There are many doors in California described as "extremely sturdy":

[image]

No skill can help to open such doors. I have found some inventive advice to open them: placing a character with meson cannon lock in front of the door but I doubt it's the best way.

Also, explosive weapons don't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [Salt Lake Park wikia page](http://wasteland.gamepedia.com/Salt_Lake_Park), I found a very similar situation with a door that could only be opened by a Meson cannon's blast. It looks like this is *one* of the only ways to open these doors.

> The trick is to get the enemy Meson cannon to shoot in its direction, as it's the only weapon capable of opening the door through the sheer force of its blast.

However, the wikia page also notes that the Meson cannon is **not** the only way to open this type of door:

> Alternatively, you can break open this locked door with a Plasma Hammer. Tested and proven on xbox1 directors cut, character used had 9pt str and 8pt blunt + Plasma Hammer.
>
> Works with a Proton Axe as well. Confirmed on PC Director's Cut, Takayuki with Strength 9 and Bladed Weapons 9 sliced it open like a can of tuna.

[This thread](https://steamcommunity.com/app/404730/discussions/0/483368526579303327/) in the Steam forums confirms this behavior:

> Those special doors can be broken down by a good knock of a Plasma Hammer. I critically hit them in all cases, so I can't say whether crits are a requirement too.

Another user in the same thread says that crits are not required for this to work:

> It looks like crits are not a requirement -- even an untrained character can do it.

Answer (score 2):

I have just started playing this game recently, and managed this feat with a Flux Reaver and Strength of 5

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to the site! We're a Q&A site, which is a bit different to a forum - we're not too worried about bumping old questions with new answers - so long as the information you are providing is relevant and useful - that's all that matters to us :). If you're interested, we do have a [tour], and a [help] which explain a bit more how our site works :)